# Getting date/time and data out of csv into matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

My end goal is to get date/time and temp data plotted by matplotlib from a csv logfile, data is formatted as such:

```
date/time,temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,ect
8/25/2017 14:55:49,20.851,20.953,21.025,21.055,ect
8/25/2017 14:56:49,20.799,20.944,20.99,21.029,ect
```

I'm trying to shoehorn my dataset into this example as a starting point:
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/date.html

As I'm still getting familiar with matplotlib, I'm not sure what the preferred inputs are, the above example uses arrays, so if that is the best option than my question is what's an efficient way to get this data into a properly formatted array? Here is my code which I got as far as reading one line of data and figuring out how to parse out the date/time and putting into a datetime container:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

f = open(r'Sample Data.csv')

#Burn off top crap of logfile
for x in range(38):
    f.readline()

#Headers
pantsHeaders = f.readline()
#Start of data
pants1 = f.readline().replace('\x00','').strip('\n').split(',')


pantsDate = datetime.date(int(pants1[0].split(' ')[0].split('/')[2]),int(pants1[0].split(' ')[0].split('/')[0]),int(pants1[0].split(' ')[0].split('/')[1]))
pantsTime = datetime.time(int(pants1[0].split(' ')[1].split(':')[0]),int(pants1[0].split(' ')[1].split(':')[1]),int(pants1[0].split(' ')[1].split(':')[2]))

date = datetime.datetime.combine(pantsDate, pantsTime)
```

There has got to be a better way to parse out the date/time info than how I'm doing it, and I'm open to any approach to get a matplotlib friendly format (arrays or otherwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is good at handling datetime formats, and it's integrated nicely with Matplotlib.

For example, with your example data:

```
datetime,temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4
8/25/2017 14:55:49,20.851,20.953,21.025,21.055
8/25/2017 14:56:49,20.799,20.944,20.99,21.029
```

If that's saved as `example.csv`, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", parse_dates=['datetime'], index_col="datetime")
df.plot()
```

[image: time series plot]

Answer (score -1):

Once you split the datetime string of your CSV, you can use strptime, as in the following example:

```
from datetime import datetime
parsed_value = '8/25/2017 14:55:49'
date = datetime.strptime(parsed_value, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(type(date))
print(date)
```

returns:

```
class 'datetime.datetime'>
2017-08-25 14:55:49

Process finished with exit code 0
```