# pandas dataset OverflowError when trying to use datetime data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Continuation from: [Getting date/time and data out of csv into matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212868/getting-date-time-and-data-out-of-csv-into-matplotlib)

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import pandas
import StringIO

f = open(r'clean data.csv')

#Make a string buffer and read in the CSV file while stripping \x00's
output = StringIO.StringIO()
for x in f.readlines():
    output.write(x.replace('\x00',''))

#Close out input file
f.close()

#Set position back to start for pandas to read
output.seek(0)
df = pandas.read_csv(output, skiprows=38, parse_dates=['Time'], index_col="Time")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index,df['108 <Air> (C)'])
#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
#ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
#fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

So I can actually plot this data with this current code, the problem occurs when I try to continue on with this example: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/date.html#sphx-glr-gallery-api-date-py

If you uncomment out

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
```

I get

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Whats up with that?

Here is some input data: https://pastebin.com/SSZyaSJ4

Comment: When I import the data directly to Pandas, without `StringIO`, I don't get that error, and the graph is displayed.  `df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.txt', skiprows=38, parse_dates=['Time'], index_col="Time")` . Does that not work for you?

Comment: It works until I uncomment out the `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())` line same as with the original

Comment: That's odd.  Are you using the file from that pastebin link exactly, without any additional formatting, as "clean data.csv"?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't appear to be the way the data is getting in. For whatever reason it seems to be working up till `fig.autofmt_xdate()` now. I feel like this is some sort of x64 based time conversion error?